# Setting processor fan to 100%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fan

How can I set fans speed to 100% or more in linux ?

Comment: Setting fan may depend on ACPI. For example on Thinkpads you use its ACPI - http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed . Please provide more details (manufacturer and preferably model).

Comment: medion WID 2000 notebook MD41205

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be aware that fiddling around with the fan speed can overheat your machine and kill components!

Anyway, the ArchLinux wiki has a [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_Speed_Control) describing how to setup `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol` to achieve speed control.

Comment: How would setting the fan to 100% cause components to overheat?

Comment: That was a general notice, if a custom tool/script does not work like intended, the system could overheat.